# NSSplitView Holding Priorities not shown in IB, why?

Tags: macos, nssplitview

I am puzzled and could swear I set my NSSplitView holding priorities in IB some days ago, but now they don't seem to be visible in IB at all.  Does anyone else see holding priorities in the top left of Xcode's IB when the splitView is selected ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your split view have subviews? I can reproduce what you're seeing if I delete all subviews from a split view. That section shows one slider for each subview.

---

Update:

You are using the new `NSSplitViewController` and `NSSplitViewItem` classes introduced with Yosemite. Because of that, your split view does not, in fact, have subviews in the NIB. (There's no triangle toggle to disclose subviews under the split view.) The split view items will provide views on demand via their view controllers.

The holding priority is a property of the split view item. I can't verify at the moment, but I expect that Xcode will provide a means to set it if you select the individual items.

Comment: Um, no it has two, one left and one right with the slide in the middle.  I just added a picture of IB

Comment: I have updated my answer. I believe the issue results from using the `NSSplitViewController` architecture and the holding priority should be set on the split view items, not the split view.

Comment: I knew I had set them somewhere !